# Hyper-V: Delete Saved State

Tags: windows, server-administration, hyper-virtualization

In Hyper-V what happens when I "delete saved state" of one Remote PC; Would I lose the data in that Remote PC? Because I have tried to increase the Ram but it didn't work.